# Replace columns of one db file with those from another

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a db file that contains data of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE songs (
id integer primary key not null,
title text not null, --title of song
composer text, --composer(s) of song
bookcode text, --book song is from
page integer, --page in book song appears on
length integer --length of song in pages
);
```

However all of the composer and length values are null and I want them to be replaced with the composer and length values from my other db file where the data is stored like:

```
  CREATE TABLE songs(
  title text NOT NULL, --title of the song
  composer text NOT NUll, --composer or composers of the song
  bookcode text NOT NULL,  --book code for the book the song is from
  page int, --page number in book where song appears
  length int, --number of pages the song occupies in the book
  studentnum text NOT NULL,  --student number of who contributed the data
  primary key (title,bookcode,page,studentnum)
  );
```

I'm trying to figure out how to access both at the same time in mySQL but sqlite3 only opens on one database at a time.

Comment: MySQL <> SQLite. I have removed MySQL tag and retagged SQLite3

Comment: Assuming you're using sqlite and not mysql... Did you look at the documentation on the sqlite website? If you did, you should have seen https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html

Answer (score 0):

You can [ATTACH](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) a database (up to 10 by default, SQLITE) to another (the primary/main) and then access both/all by using the schema **main** for the initial/primary/main database and the named schema (as per the AS keyword) for the other attached databases.

e.g. :-

```
DETACH test002;
ATTACH 'D:\Databases\SQLite\Navicat Databases\test002.db' AS test002;
SELECT * FROM main.sqlite_master;
SELECT * FROM test002.sqlite_master;
PRAGMA database_list; -- List the attached databases
```

Results from the above (just to show proof of concept) :-

[image]

[image]

[image]

Re comment

> The terminal says that the command ATTACH is not found

Rarely a user of the command line but the following shows **ATTACH** being used via command prompt :-

> ```
> C:\Users\Mike>sqlite3
> SQLite version 3.22.0 2018-01-22 18:45:57
> Enter ".help" for usage hints.
> Connected to a transient in-memory database.
> Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
> sqlite> ATTACH 'D:\Databases\SQLite\Navicat Databases\test002.db' AS test002;
> sqlite> ATTACH 'D:\Databases\SQLite\Navicat Databases\gransha.db' AS test001;
> sqlite> SELECT * FROM test002.sqlite_master;
> table|phonebook|phonebook|2|CREATE TABLE phonebook(name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, phonenumber TEXT)
> index|sqlite_autoindex_phonebook_1|phonebook|3|
> sqlite> SELECT * FROM test001.sqlite_master;
> table|_Questions_old_20180428|_Questions_old_20180428|2|CREATE TABLE "_Questions_old_20180428" (
>   "_QuestionID" INTEGER NOT NULL,
>   "QuestionResult" integer,
>   "QuestionTypeID" INTEGER,
>   "QuestionTopicID" INTEGER,
>   "LogUserID" INTEGER,
>   PRIMARY KEY ("_QuestionID")
> ) ............
> ```

Comment: Appears that you've not installed SQLite properly or are not using the command line properly.